# How can I click an element with the same name after scrolling into view

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to click onto 'Users' that is already under the sub menu of 'Users'

I have tried using a different identifier like "dx-item dx-treeview-item" and named it as a different element but cypress wasn't able to find it.

My test

```
 describe('CanGoToUsers' , function() {
    it('GoToUsers', function(){
         const dashboard = new DashBoardPage;
         cy.visit('/');
         cy.login();
         dashboard.Users().scrollIntoView()
         dashboard.UsersClick().click();

         
    });
```

dashboard page

```
Users(){
    return cy.contains('Users')
}

UsersClick(){
    return cy.get('dx-item dx-treeview-item')
}
```

[Picture of the nav-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgEZO.jpg)

html element

```
<ul class="dx-treeview-node-container dx-treeview-node-container-opened" role="group">
   <li class="dx-treeview-node dx-treeview-item-without-checkbox dx-state-selected dx-treeview-node-is-leaf" data-item-id="/Users" role="treeitem" aria-label="Users" aria-expanded="false" aria-level="2" aria-selected="true">
      <div class="dx-item dx-treeview-item">
         <div class="dx-item-content dx-treeview-item-content"><span>Users</span></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="dx-treeview-node dx-treeview-item-without-checkbox dx-treeview-node-is-leaf" data-item-id="/settings/roles" role="treeitem" aria-label="Roles" aria-expanded="false" aria-level="2" aria-selected="false">
      <div class="dx-item dx-treeview-item">
         <div class="dx-item-content dx-treeview-item-content"><span>Roles</span></div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="dx-treeview-node dx-treeview-item-without-checkbox dx-treeview-node-is-leaf" data-item-id="/settings/permissions" role="treeitem" aria-label="Permissions" aria-expanded="false" aria-level="2" aria-selected="false">
      <div class="dx-item dx-treeview-item">
         <div class="dx-item-content dx-treeview-item-content"><span>Permissions</span></div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add HTML of the tested element.

Comment: added i think sorry it's in one line

Comment: I saw that you're using the Page Object Model design pattern. You may want to read [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/#page-objects) article, where Cypress developers discuss the cons of said pattern and provide a different solution.

Comment: The selectors in `cy.get('dx-item dx-treeview-item')` are classes, so you need a dot in front of them `cy.get('.dx-item .dx-treeview-item')`

Comment: @natn2323 You should also read the comments to the linked blog post. That approach is "debatable" at best.

Comment: Thanks, @danzel. Yes, the article provides a _different_ solution, not necessarily a _better_ solution. For it to be a better or worse solution would depend on the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data-item-id` attribute to find the element to click it

```
cy.get('li[data-item-id="/Users"]').click()

//In case the above doesn't work you can try this
cy.get('li[data-item-id="/Users"]').click({force: true})
```

Comment: You should also remove the `li` from the selector, so that your test doesn't rely on the HTML structure